# Update from stored procedure

Tags: postgresql, sql-injection, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I need to create a stored procedure which can take in the schema name and table name as the parameter and make an update on the same table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION garscratch.update_table(schema_name text, table_name text ) RETURNS void as $$
DECLARE
 table TEXT;
BEGIN
execute 'update '||schema||'.'||table_name|| 'set id = substring(id from 1 for 2) where name = "test"';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I execute the procedure above as:

```
select update_table(my,my_table);
```

I get the error:

> Column "my" does not exist.

It does not treat "my" as the schema name.

Comment: @Your: This clearly concerns SQL injection. Identifiers have to be treated as user input and sanitized for dynamic SQL. That's actually the most important problem here. A missing blank is easily solved.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter ok, fair point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You'd need a space between `tablename` and `set`.
- You need sinlge quotes around the value `'test'`.
  Or if it's supposed to be a column name, you don't need quotes at all.
- You need to sanitize identifiers to avoid SQL injection.

Use instead (complete rewrite):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION garscratch.update_table(_tbl regclass)
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
BEGIN
EXECUTE 'UPDATE ' || _tbl || $$ SET id = left(id, 2) WHERE name = 'test'$$;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT garscratch.update_table('myschema.my_table');
```

Detailed explanation:
[Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you may have problem with the `table_name|| 'set id=` part - specifically I think you should add a space between `'` and `set`. Try to print what you're executing and you may found out where the problem may be.

Answer (score 0):

Execute Procedure as below:

```
select update_table('my','my_table');
```

Also change line

```
execute 'update '||schema||'.'||table_name|| 'set id = substring(id from 1 for 2) where name = "test"';
```

to

```
execute 'update '||schema_name||'.'||table_name|| 'set id = substring(id from 1 for 2) where name = "test"';
```